# scipy kmeans iteration meaning?

Tags: scipy, k-means

I am using the kmeans2 algorithm from scipy to cluster pixel colors in an image to get the top  average colors in the image.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans2.html#scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans2

I am confused on the meaning for this parameter:

```
iter : int
Number of iterations of the k-means algrithm to run. Note that this differs in meaning from the iters parameter to the kmeans function.
```

If I want the kmeans algorithm to run until the clusters don't change, would I set the `iter` value high?  Is there a way to find a *best* `iter` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The K-means algorithm works by initializing some K points and clustering your data by their distance from those points.  Then it iterates by calculating the centroid of each cluster and redefining clusters by distance from the centroid.  This isn't guaranteed to converge quickly, though it often does, so it's asking for a *maximum iteration value.*

edit: *maximum iteration value.* is incorrect I think, it is literally going to iterate `iter` times.  The default `10` is a common iter value, though.

The higher the iter value the better the clustering.  You could try running K-means on some of your data with various iter values and seeing where the time to compute for some gain in cluster quality is too high for your needs.

Comment: Ah ok, so if I set `iter=9999`, it won't iterate 9999 necessarily, but until it converges

Comment: Is there a way to iterate infinitely?  Also is there a way to show how many iterations have occurred when it converges?

Comment: I'm unsure about scipy, however it should be straight forward to re-implement kmeans to your liking, but with numpy and scipy modules to maintain speed.